# Boolean and logical operators

Tags: oz, mozart

I'm a begginer in Mozart-Oz, and I seek help because this language is not very intuitive, and lacks documentation.

I'm trying to apply this code (which works on eclipse when i write it in java) and doesn't work in oz, here are the details:

This is the code in Oz, it **displays True** (which is not logical since if A is true and B is false, A And B should be false)

```
declare
A=true
B=false
C=A And B
{Browse C}
```

This the code in Java, **which displays False** (It is the logical answer)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean A=true;
    boolean B=false;
    boolean C=A && B;
    System.out.println(C);

}
```

Comment: And what does that `Browse` do exactly?

Comment: @Kyle Spencer it acts like System.out.printLn(C), it displays on screen, and in my case it shows true once i compile the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, apparently you have to treat And as a function not an operator. By using this syntax

{And true false}
it will return false.

Comment: There is also an Operator: `andthen`. The semantics are slightly different. `andthen` does not evaluate its second argument if the first is False.